# What am I missing in this simple test to see how parallel tasks could be run in C# (they're processing sequentially)?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task

I've read through a bunch of questions and answers on running parallel tasks and wanted to make a simple test that would let me know I understood the basics of how it works.

```
    public async Task sleeper(int s)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(s);
    }

    public async Task t1()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("T1: " + i);
            await sleeper(5000);
        }
    }

    public async Task t2()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("T2: " + i);
            await sleeper(3000);
        }
    }

    public async Task runIt()
    {
        var task1 = t1();
        var task2 = t2();
        await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
        Console.WriteLine("got it");
    }
```

I expected something like:
T1: 0
T2: 0
T1: 1
T1: 2
T2: 1
etc

instead I get sequential processing of t1 and t2:
T1: 0
T1: 1
T1: 2
...
T1: 9
T2: 0
T2: 1
etc

I'm sure I'm missing something silly but maybe I'm not the only one. What's wrong here?

Comment: Aren't you getting a compilation warning about an `async` method that lacks an `await` operator?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yep, completely missed it. still glad i asked, learned something new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, and you have the right idea, but you're not actually utilising async/await, because you're not `await`-ing anything inside `sleeper`.

The idea behind asynchronous code is for the thread to go an do something else while it waits for a thing that takes a while. `Thread.Sleep` is used to **block** a thread for the specified amount of time, which means that thread is stuck; it can't go do something else.

In this case, that causes your code to run synchronously. In other cases, blocking a thread within async calls [can be much worse](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

So to fix your example, instead of using `Thread.Sleep`, which is not intended for asynchronous use, use `Task.Delay`, which is.

```cs
public async Task sleeper(int s)
{
    await Task.Delay(s * 1000); // Task.Delay is in milliseconds
}
```